# Hyperledger chaincode "register" vs "deploy"

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I see the following ref post for "what-happened-exactly-on-chaincode-deploy-and-invoke-query-in-hyperledger".

For the "register" chaincode, is that the chaincode author has to register the chaincode to the ValidationPeer before other nodes can find the chaincode in the network and download the source to their local and build docker image? What happens if the same chaincode gets deployed multiple times afterwards, will it overwrite previous state?

Reference:
[What happened exactly on chaincode deploy and invoke , query, in Hyperledger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607263/what-happened-exactly-on-chaincode-deploy-and-invoke-query-in-hyperledger)

During “Deploy” the chain code is submitted to the ledger in a form of transaction and distributed to all nodes in the network. Each node creates new Docker container with this chaincode embedded. After that container will be started and Init method will be executed.

During “Query” - chain code will read the current state and send it back to user. This transaction is not saved in blockchain.

During “Invoke” - chaincode can modify the state of the variables in ledger. Each “Invoke” transaction will be added to the “block” in the ledger.

Answer (score 3):

Haven’t seen the “register” feature on chaincode level. I can make an assumption (please correct me if I am wrong) that we are speaking about core API method “Registrar”

“Registrar” is used by chaincode’s author to login to the network via Validation or Non-Validation peer. In order to login author should confirm his identity by providing EnrolmentID and EnrolmentPassword. If ID and Password are correct, new Enrolment and Transaction certificates will be generated for this particular author.

From this moment author can deploy chaincode to the network. “Deploy” request will be send to one of peers. This peer will create “transaction” with information about “path to chaincode”, “init arguments”, “chaincode source code”. Then peer will calculate the HASH code for this transaction which looks like this:

```
a13c53fe822da398aaca7af59f064ae6f85c1d048fcb2ed77c3cacc137964a424deba679390df8d156e49c5fff7cdfc9fecec373a3cddd17e46ca9404096a52d
```

This hash will be used later as chaincode name.

VP keeps open connection to all other VPs in a network and can broadcast transaction to all of them (see consensus description for more details).
Every peer will use information from transaction to create local docker image required for deployed chaincode. Start new docker container, and execute Init method.

If you try to deploy the same chaincode again, Fabric will detect that chaincode with such name is already deployed and skip initialisation.

If you change anything in deploy request  (path, arguments, any symbol in chaincode), peer will generate another hash and will deploy new chaincode (previous version will not be affected).

Comment: Thanks you, Sergey,

For register, I'm actually referring to the following in the hyperledger doc:
..........
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup/
Starting and registering the chaincode

Run the following chaincode command to start and register the chaincode with the validating peer:

CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02
The chaincode console will display the message “Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations”, which indicates that the chaincode is ready to receive requests.

Comment: This example describes how to run Fabric in development mode (—peer-chaincodedev). In this mode you can run your chaincode using arbitrary name. Chaincode will be run as process in local environment (without docker containers). Developers can use this mode for debugging purposes because it works faster and gives an access to debug messages from chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

Technically REGISTER is part of the Deploy transaction

Chaincode provides Deploy, Invoke, Query methods/APIs to interact with it. When you talk about deploying a chiancode you are actually talking about an end user(or an application) calling the Deploy method on a chaincode.

Peer processing the Deploy transaction, starts the chaincode in a Docker container, but the Deploy transaction processing does not end here. There is a shim layer on chaincode container which actually communicates with the peer henceforth. This communication between shim layer and peer is governed by ChaincodeMessage. There are different types of ChaincodeMessage(s) as defined by this declaration:

```
enum Type {
    UNDEFINED = 0;
    REGISTER = 1;
    REGISTERED = 2;
    INIT = 3;
    READY = 4;
    TRANSACTION = 5;
    COMPLETED = 6;
    ERROR = 7;
    GET_STATE = 8;
    PUT_STATE = 9;
    DEL_STATE = 10;
    INVOKE_CHAINCODE = 11;
    INVOKE_QUERY = 12;
    RESPONSE = 13;
    QUERY = 14;
    QUERY_COMPLETED = 15;
    QUERY_ERROR = 16;
    RANGE_QUERY_STATE = 17;
}
```

Now quoting from the source http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-spec/#33-chaincode:

```
Upon deploy (chaincode container is started), the shim layer sends a one
time REGISTER message to the validating peer with the payload containing the 
ChaincodeID. The validating peer responds with REGISTERED or ERROR on 
success or failure respectively. The shim closes the connection and exits if 
it receives an ERROR.
```

Hence you get

```
10:08:38.450 [shim] DEBU : Registering.. sending REGISTER
10:08:39.901 [shim] DEBU : []Received message REGISTERED from shim
10:08:39.965 [shim] DEBU : []Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTERED(state:created)
10:08:40.037 [shim] DEBU : Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations
```

after which your chaincode is actually ready to receive Query and Invoke.